# How to test if my installer contains a file?

Tags: install4j

We've built an installer using install4j. The resulting executable comes in various flavours for different version of the software an may contain different languages. At some point during the installation process, the user can choose, which languages should be installed. Therefore a step containing a list of checkboxes is presented. I now want to test what languages are included in the installer and customize the list accordingly.

My question is: Is there a way to test what files are included / present in the installer at runetime? Or do I have to check this at build time and include a variable or something?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to enumerate the contained files in the installer. You would have to use files sets, installation components or define compiler variables in your project.

Comment: I'm a little confused because you wrote "**or** define compiler variables". You mean I have to use compiler variable no matter if I use file sets or installation components, right?

Comment: If you add file sets or installation components for each language, you do not need compiler variables. You can query file sets and installation components via the API.